# Local kubeadm K8S access to private gcr.io

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubectl, kubelet

I have installed K8S with `kubeadm` and `docker 18.09.4` and it works fine. Then I installed `gcloud`, ran `gcloud init` and select my project where `gcr` is activated, continued with `gcloud components install kubectl docker-credentials-gcr`, followed by `docker-credentials-gcr configure-docker`.

At that stage, `docker` can pull images from my own `gcr` registry, while `kubelet` cannot.

Basically, if I run `docker run --rm --name hello gcr.io/own-gcr/hello-world` it pulls the image from the registry and starts the container.
If I delete the image from my local registry and ran `` it fails with the following description:

```
  Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From                       Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----                       -------
  Normal   Scheduled  23s                default-scheduler          Successfully assigned default/node-hello-6b99957775-9dvvw to lfr025922-docker
  Normal   BackOff    20s (x2 over 21s)  kubelet, lfr025922-docker  Back-off pulling image "gcr.io/own-gcr/node-hello"
  Warning  Failed     20s (x2 over 21s)  kubelet, lfr025922-docker  Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling    9s (x2 over 22s)   kubelet, lfr025922-docker  Pulling image "gcr.io/own-gcr/node-hello"
  Warning  Failed     9s (x2 over 21s)   kubelet, lfr025922-docker  Failed to pull image "gcr.io/own-gcr/node-hello": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication
  Warning  Failed     9s (x2 over 21s)   kubelet, lfr025922-docker  Error: ErrImagePull
```

I of course, followed all instructions on page https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication and none of them were successful.

Are you aware of any issue with `kubelet 1.14` and `docker 18.09.5`? Isn't `kubelet` supposed to rely on the underlying `CRI` (here `docker`)? Have you any idea of what could cause that issue?

Comment: have you tried "gcloud auth configure-docker"?

Comment: yes I did. Sorry about that. Forgot this step in my above listing. And I have the exact same behavior before and after running this command, which changed my ~/.docker/config.json file from 
`{
  "credHelpers": {
    "gcr.io": "gcr", 
    "us.gcr.io": "gcr", 
    "asia.gcr.io": "gcr", 
    "staging-k8s.gcr.io": "gcr", 
    "eu.gcr.io": "gcr"
  }
}` to
`{
  "credHelpers": {
    "gcr.io": "gcloud", 
    "us.gcr.io": "gcloud", 
    "eu.gcr.io": "gcloud", 
    "asia.gcr.io": "gcloud", 
    "staging-k8s.gcr.io": "gcloud", 
    "marketplace.gcr.io": "gcloud"
  }
}`

Comment: see here: https://container-solutions.com/using-google-container-registry-with-kubernetes/

Comment: I suspect that kubelet can use existing Docker credentials only if they are published as is, without any helper tools.

Comment: Thanks @VasilyAngapov. I was reading that page when you comment pop out. And it's the good place to be. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@VasilyAngapov was true.

I followed the tricks provided here https://container-solutions.com/using-google-container-registry-with-kubernetes/ and it works perfectly well (using the Access Token with `oauth2accesstoken`)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Keep in mind that oauth2accesstoken is short lived token, it will not work forever. For long term solution you should use Google serviceaccounts and JSON token.